# How Can I apply Dense layer after keras ResNet?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

How can apply a Dense layer after ResNet50?
It is my code

```
    def build_model():
       x = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(input_shape=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, 3), weights=None, 
       include_top=False, pooling='avg')
       model = tf.keras.layers.Dense(196)(x)
       model.summary()
       return model
```

but I got this error:

```
TypeError: Inputs to a layer should be tensors.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access the output of the model with the property `output` of the model, if you are willing to recreate a model using the functional API. In that case, it could be easier to use the Sequential API though:

#### Sequential API:

```
new_model = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [
        tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(input_shape=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, 3), weights=None, include_top=False, pooling='avg'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(196)
    ]
)
new_model.summary()
```

#### Functional API :

```
resnet = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(input_shape=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, 3), weights=None, include_top=False, pooling='avg')
out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(196)(resnet.output)
new_model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=resnet.input, outputs=out)
new_model.summary()
```